# node.js global queue memory leak no matter what is tried

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, queue

I am using Node.js 14 LTS and Express 4.17.1. I am trying to build a global queue that can take JSON payload, store it in the queue and dispatch as a group when the queue is a given size.

The issue that I'm facing is that the garbage collection time vastly increases, which will mean that the Node.js app will eventually become non responsive and maybe crash. No matter if I use the code below, simple arrays, or use contained classes, it is the same thing.

Essentially this is a memory leak even though I'm clearing the arrays, classes or singleton array each time it is dispatched.

I believe this is due to the reference in the root of the file so Node's garbage collection can't release it from memory and therefore grows.

I wonder if you have an alternative that can accomplish similarly but not increase the HEAP?

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to get working without leaks:

```
"use strict";
import Singleton from '../services/Singleton.js'
import Queue from '../services/Queue.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const bulkESNumber = parseInt(process.env.BULK_ES_NUMER)
let ts_queue = null
let ts_singleton = null
router.post('/:es_indice/:id?', async (req, res) => {
  if (!ts_queue) {
    ts_queue = new Queue();
    ts_singleton = new Singleton(ts_queue);
    ts_queue = null
  }

  let ts_q = ts_singleton.getInstance()
  if ( bulkESNumber > await ts_q.size()) {
    await ts_q.add(req)
    console.log(await ts_q.size())
  } else {
    console.log('dispatche t2_s queue')
    ts_q.clear()  
  }
})
```

The Queue Class:

```
"use strict";

class Queue {
  queue = null
  constructor() {
    this.queue = []
  }

  async add(item) {
    this.queue.push(item)
  }

  async clear() {
    this.queue = []
  }

  async get() {
    return this.queue
  }

  async size() {
    return this.queue.length
  }
}

export default Queue
```

The Singleton Class:

```
class Singleton {

  constructor(obj_instance) {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = obj_instance;
    }
  }

  getInstance() {
    return Singleton.instance;
  }
}

export default Singleton
```

If you are brave enough to scroll through this next section below you'll see that the time between garbage collection and HEAP size both keep increasing throughout the process. This means that the app becomes less responsive to the POSTs and eventually will crash.

I trigger this by posting to an  endpoint that POSTs a json payload that should be stored in the queue

This is how I start the server with a heap trace:

> >$ node --trace_gc --use_strict index.js

> > server running on port: http://127.0.0.1:3232

> > > [14071:0x110008000]      376 ms: Mark-sweep 16.6 (28.7) -> 11.1 (28.8) MB, 2.3 / 0.1 ms  (+ 0.1 ms in 3 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 16 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested

> > > 1

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:20.233Z info:   Event elasped time 3ms

> > > 2

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:21.717Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > 3

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:22.659Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > 4

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:23.649Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > ...

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:25.307Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > [14101:0x110008000]     8531 ms: Mark-sweep 12.4 (29.0) -> 11.4 (14.3) MB, 7.7 / 0.1 ms  (+ 0.8 ms in 4 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.5 ms, walltime since start of marking 35 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested

> > > 7

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:26.035Z info:   Event elasped time 2ms

> > > [14101:0x110008000]     9168 ms: Mark-sweep 11.5 (14.3) -> 11.4 (14.3) MB, 5.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.5 ms in 4 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 32 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.991) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested

> > > 8

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:28.032Z info:   Event elasped time 5ms
> > > ...

> > > 9

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:38.027Z info:   Event elasped time 0ms

> > > 10

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:38.643Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > dispatche t2_s queue

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:39.316Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > 1

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:40.029Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > 2

> > > [14101:0x110008000]    23392 ms: Scavenge 12.5 (14.3) -> 11.7 (14.3) MB, 0.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.991) allocation failure

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:40.753Z info:   Event elasped time 2ms

...

> > > 5

> > > 2021-06-14T22:53:49.131Z info:   Event elasped time 1ms

> > > [14101:0x110008000]    32322 ms: Scavenge 12.5 (14.3) -> 11.8 (14.3) MB, 0.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.991) allocation failure

Comment: We are also hitting wired GC and memory leak with nodejs looking for some solutions on this thread.